# Specific Layout positioning in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, layout

I know this is common to ask but I'm having a trouble on how can I place the `change password button` beside `edit button` like the example image below, I tried app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="id" but it doesn't work, Is there anyway how can I manage in layout, I've keep searching till yet not found the answer, need help

[image]

**activity_main.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EditProfile">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolView_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:background="@color/primary" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/txtProfileDetails"
                        android:text="Profile Details"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="205dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
                            android:text="Change Password"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cc_idno"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:helperText="Mandatory"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_series"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtProfileDetails"
                   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="ID number"
                            android:id="@+id/edt_idno"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:layout_below="@id/edtFirstname"/>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_logo"
                    app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageview_account_profile"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Bro play with the visibility of UI Widgets and you will find you solution.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

Comment: @success_anil Thanks for your response I also read the documentation but I can't find yet the best position of layout, I think there's some trick of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your both the concerned buttons inside a linearlayout and it will work. with horizontal orientation .

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right">


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
                            android:layout_width="205dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="Change Password"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/editProfile"
                            android:layout_width="45dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"

                           />

                    </LinearLayout>
```